# Which top player risks complicated positions?

Tags: famous-players, aggressive-play

Which current top player (at least 2600 ELO) does not avoid complicated positions
 in important classic tournament games, even if they are risky ?

This is closely related to the question which player is most aggressive and
 compromiseless.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Current top player with most aggressive style?](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8818/current-top-player-with-most-aggressive-style)

Comment: Perhaps not the most aggressive and risky player but nakamura doesn't offer draws.

Comment: Richard Rapport.

Answer (score 4):

As wrote in my answer to your other question: Jobava and Mamedyarov play very aggressively.

Ding Liren and Arkadij Naiditsch are another two top players who regularly risk absolute chaos on the board.

Answer (score 1):

Topalov definitely. See his games at Gibraltar especially against lower rated opposition.

Comment: Topalov could almost be called semi-retired now. And if you look at games against significantly lower rated opponents even Kramnik qualifies as risk taker. That being said, Topalov played a lot of crazy games in his heyday. Just look at his games in Linares '10, for example against Grischuk http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1573295.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I don't believe the question mentioned activity as a prerequisite. Topalov has form for risk taking.

Answer (score 0):

I have to tell you honestly, Michael Adams is the top in that. Lots of his 2700-level games are absolute craziness.

Comment: Well, the Mickey Adams I know, is more of a positional grinder and Berlin endgame player.

Comment: He only took up the Berlin recently and has played the open Sicilian for years so that is misguided.

Comment: Playing the open sicilian doesn't make you a risk taker. Karpov played the open sicilian as well. As does Carlsen occasionally. All grinders. Mickey Adams isn't called the spider for nothing.

Comment: But playing the open Sicilian with castling on opposite sides is risk taking. See any number of games Adams plays in the Najdorf in the English attack. A lot of losses against Kasparov, Gelfand and 2700 GMs but he's still taking risks. Adams has played 1.e4 for his entire career, whereas Carlsen, Karpov etc are mainly 1.d4 players. You can be a positional spider while still taking risks.

Comment: He does grind sometimes, but the games I analyzed a few years back shown his risk-taking side, and he's a master of it. :)

Comment: Here's a fun game :D 
http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1247769